# How to detect processor correct temperature in conky

Tags: temperature, conky, sensors

I am using `conky&conkyforecast` to have a nice widget containing some system information and weather data.

But I can see that the temperature that conky shows is different than the one I get running in terminal `sensors`.

Conky script line:
`Temperature: ${alignr}${acpitemp}°C`

Running `sensors` in terminat gets this:

```
florin@florin-Satellite-C650:~$ sensors
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +49.0°C  (crit = +110.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +51.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
Core 2:       +60.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
```

Conky shows 49° temperature.

How can I make them show the same temperature? What does conky show over there?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The temperature indeed is 49º, so what is the problem?

Answer (score 9):

### Temperature from command line

To find out the temperature, use:

```
# Ivybridge Intel i7-3630QM
$ cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp
69000
69000
67000

# Skylake Intel i7-6700HQ using paste after zone names
$ paste <(cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/type) <(cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp) | column -s $'\t' -t
INT3400 Thermal  20000
SEN1             53000
SEN2             49000
SEN3             53000
SEN4             55000
pch_skylake      70000
B0D4             47000
x86_pkg_temp     48000
```

### Temperature with Conky

Within `conky` the system variable I used to monitor an Ivy Bridge CPU is:

```
${hwmon 2 temp 1}°C
```

To monitor a Skylake CPU I initially used:

```
${hwmon 0 temp 1}°C
```

A few months later (possibly due to new kernel) on the same Skylake CPU I switched to:

```
${hwmon 1 temp 1}°C
```

The display looks like this:

[image: Conky Temperature 4.8.10]

Answer (score 7):

I found that this worked for me:

```
${platform coretemp.0 temp 1}
```

This reads the temperature info from `/sys/devices/platform/coretemp.0/temp1_input`.

Comment: For some reason I had to change this `${platform coretemp.0/hwmon/hwmon0 temp 1}` because `temp1_input` only exists in `/sys/devices/platform/coretemp.0/hwmon/hwmon0/temp1_input` on my system (Debian sid)

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04 w/Skylake processor I used: `cat /sys/devices/platform/coretemp.0/hwmon/hwmon1/temp*_input` to get four temperatures one for each CPU.

Answer (score 4):

Another possible solution is:

```
$(exec sensors | grep 'Package id' | awk '{print $4}')
```

Output:

```
+33.0°C
```

Answer (score 3):

Another possible solution is:

```
${exec cat /sys/devices/platform/coretemp.0/temp1_input | cut -c-2 }
```

or if that doesn't work:

```
${exec cat /sys/devices/platform/coretemp.0/hwmon/hwmon1/temp1_input | cut -c-2 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution.
Use find command;

`find /sys/devices/platform/ -iname '*input'`

Output:

```
/sys/devices/platform/coretemp.0/hwmon/hwmon2/temp3_input
/sys/devices/platform/coretemp.0/hwmon/hwmon2/temp2_input
```

Conky variable;

```
${hwmon 2 temp 2}°C
${hwmon 2 temp 3}°C
```

Comment: Thank you. The ' find /sys/devices/platform/ -iname '*input' ' takes all the guesswork out of tracking down the right hwmon hook.

Comment: I like this one! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`${exec sensors | grep 'Package id' | awk '{print $4}'}`

`Sensors CPU: ${exec sensors | grep 'Package id' | awk '{print $4}'}`

Answer (score 0):

A simple one liner:

```
cd /sys/bus/platform/drivers/coretemp/coretemp.0/hwmon/hwmon*;for i in $(ls -1 temp*_label|cut -b 5);do tempSensor=$(cat temp"$i"_label);tempVal=$(cat temp"$i"_input);echo $tempSensor"    "$tempVal;done;cd $OLDPWD
```

Comment: Simple (comparing to other solutions offered) - not sure. One liner? Looks like a whole shell script compressed into one line.

Comment: If you're looking for a one-liner, this isn't one.